# Extracting first and last element from sublists in nested list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How do you extract the first and last elements from each sublist in a nested list?

For example:

```
x=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print(x)
#[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

The desired result-

```
[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]]
```

This is the closest I've seen-

```
a = [x[i][i] for i in (0, -1)]
print(a)
#[1, 9]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the right idea. If your list inside list is only one layer deep, you can access the first and last elements with a list comprehension and -1 indexing like you were trying to do:

```
a = [[sublist[0],sublist[-1]] for sublist in x]
```

Output:

```
>>> a
[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can use list slices:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
x = [l[::len(l)-1] for l in x]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

>>> [a[:1] + a[-1:] for a in x]
[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]]
```

I extract 2 slices, one with the first element, one with the last, and concatenate them.
It will works even when sublist are of different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
for item in x:
    print(item[0], item[2])
```

For your exact desired result, use this:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
new_list = []
for item in x:
    new_list.append([item[0], item[2]])

print(new_list)
```

Comment: Better not to hardcode the length of the sublists and use item[-1] instead

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing it like this. The `list[-1]` syntax is meant to get the last element in a list which is what you want.

```py
x=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

for elem in x:
    print(elem[0], elem[-1])
```

This just prints them in a standard format but to put them back into a new list in this order would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list and access them from there:

```
x=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

out = []
for arr in x:
    out.append([arr[0], arr[-1]])

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]]
```

Furthermore, you can use list comprehension:

```
out = [[arr[0], arr[-1]] for arr in x]
```