# Extracting the last items from nested lists in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, data-science

I have some nested lists. I want to extract the last occurring element within each sublist (eg 'bye' for the first sublist). I then want to add all these last occurring elements ('bye', 'bye', 'hello' and 'ciao') to a new list so that I can count them easily, and find out which is the most frequently occurring one ('bye).

The problem is that my code leaves me with an empty list. I've looked at [Extracting first and last element from sublists in nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822696/extracting-first-and-last-element-from-sublists-in-nested-list) and [How to extract the last item from a list in a list of lists? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63199461/how-to-extract-the-last-item-from-a-list-in-a-list-of-lists-python) and they're not exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks for any help!

```
my_list = [['hello', 'bye', 'bye'], ['hello', 'bye', 'bye'], ['hello', 'hello', 'hello'], ['hello', 'bye', 'ciao']]

# Make a new list of all of the last elements in the sublists
new_list = []
for sublist in my_list:
    for element in sublist:
        if sublist.index(element) == -1:
            new_list.append(element)

# MY OUTPUT
print(new_list)
[]
        
# EXPECTED OUTPUT 
['bye', 'bye', 'hello', 'ciao']


# I would then use new_list to find out what the most common last element is:
most_common = max(set(new_list), key = new_list.count) 

# Expected final output
print(most_common)
# 'bye'
```

Comment: how this [How to extract the last item from a list in a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63199461/how-to-extract-the-last-item-from-a-list-in-a-list-of-lists-python) is different from your question?

Comment: @deadshot That one has deeper nesting, and requires different output.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this:

```
for sublist in my_list:
  new_list.append(sublist[-1])
```

The index `-1` does not "really exist", it is a way to tell python to start counting from the end of the list. That is why you will not get a match when looking for `-1` like you do it.
Additionally, you are walking over all the lists, which is not necessary, as you have "random access" by fetching the last item as you can see in my code.

There is even a more pythonic way to do this using list comprehensions:

```
new_list = [sublist[-1] for sublist in my_list]
```

Then you do not need any of those `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the last element of a list by calling the index -1, e.g. `sublist[-1]`. The following code should give you your expected result:

```
my_list = [['hello', 'bye', 'bye'], ['hello', 'bye', 'bye'], ['hello', 'hello', 'hello'], ['hello', 'bye', 'ciao']]

new_list = list()
for sublist in my_list:
    new_list.append(sublist[-1])

print(new_list)
```

or as Risoko pointed out, you can do it in one line, so the code should look like

```
my_list = [['hello', 'bye', 'bye'], ['hello', 'bye', 'bye'], ['hello', 'hello', 'hello'], ['hello', 'bye', 'ciao']]

new_list = [sublist[-1] for sublist in my_list]

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
output = [sublist[-1] for sublist in my_list]
```